# boost msm, how can I determine if a transition occurred?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-msm

When I fire process_event("eventname"),  How can I check if the state transition occurred or if no_transition was called?

Basically, I would like that the class that fires/calls process_event("eventname") be able to tell if the transition occurred. Currently I can't determine this.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of process_event is:

```
typedef enum
{
    HANDLED_FALSE=0,
    HANDLED_TRUE =1,
    HANDLED_GUARD_REJECT=2,
    HANDLED_DEFERRED=4
} HandledEnum;
```

What you want is probably all except `HANDLED_FALSE`, which comes with `no_transition`.

Comment: Hi Christophe, I realised you are the author for boost msm, and I have a question that I don't seem to get an answer to. would you be able to help me? I am sorry I found no other way to contact you. The question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421537/boost-msm-problems-with-events-and-state-reuse

Comment: I answered on the boost mailing list. I'm checking it much more regularly than SO.